# Filling PDF Form from PowerShell - iText7

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext7

I can't figure out why I'm not able to write the PDF Form field. I'm able to read the form, but not able to update it.

```
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.forms.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.layout.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\Common.Logging.3.4.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\Common.Logging.Core.3.4.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\Portable.BouncyCastle.1.8.5\lib\netstandard1.3\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"

$Reader = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\temp\input.pdf")
$Reader.SetUnethicalReading($True)
$Writer = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new("C:\temp\output.pdf")
$PdfDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($Reader, $Writer)
$Form = [iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm]::getAcroForm($PdfDoc, $False)

$Field = $Form.GetField("MyField")
Write-Host $Field # Writes the value in the form-field of input.pdf
$Field.SetValue("Foo Bar")
$PdfDoc.Close()
```

I end up with:
`Exception calling "SetValue" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

I tried to do it in C#, and it was working ok, but I don't get it to work in PowerShell.

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

PdfReader reader = new(@"C:\temp\input.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new(@"C:\temp\output.pdf");
PdfDocument doc = new(reader, writer);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(doc, false);

var test = form.GetField("MyField").GetValueAsString();

var field = form.GetField("MyField");
field.SetValue("Foo Bar");
doc.Close();
```

Thanks for advices!

Comment: according to https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/#dependencies-tab your version of BouncyCastle is too old.
What the output of $Field.GetAlternativeName() before trying to write inside ?

Comment: I'll check the dependencies!

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the comments, you have issues with your dependencies. Just look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/ and you will see a lot of dependencies required by this package.

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to debug this problem but I was able to make it works so I will share how I got this and hope more experienced members can improve this answer. First, here is the code:

```
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\common.logging.core.3.4.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\common.logging.3.4.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\portable.bouncycastle.1.8.9\lib\netstandard2.0\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\itext7.commons.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.commons.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.forms.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\itext7.7.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.layout.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\microsoft.extensions.options.5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\microsoft.extensions.logging.5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\system.text.encoding.codepages.5.0.0\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll"

$Reader = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\temp\input.pdf")
$Reader.SetUnethicalReading($True)
Remove-Item "C:\temp\output.pdf" -Force -ea SilentlyContinue
$Writer = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new("C:\temp\output.pdf")

$PdfDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($Reader, $Writer)
$Form = [iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm]::getAcroForm($PdfDoc, $False)

$Field = $Form.GetField("MyField")
Write-Host $Field # Writes the value in the form-field of input.pdf
$Field.SetValue("Foo Bar",$false)
$PdfDoc.Close()
```

**Missing Depencies**

Once you have a dependency exception, just look at the variable `$error[0].Exception.GetBaseException().LoaderExceptions`

For exemple, try to load `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` without `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`, you will get an error. And the details of the missing dependency(ies) will be available in this variable.

**Missing Argument on SetValue**

Once all the dependencies are fine, you can focus on the error message: `Exception calling "SetValue" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` Almost the same way as previous step, you need to dig into `$error` variable which is a gold mine.
After executing line `$Field.SetValue("Foo Bar")` run `$Error[0].Exception.GetBaseException().StackTrace` to get the details:
à iText.Layout.Renderer.TextPreprocessingUtil.ReplaceSpecialWhitespaceGlyphs(GlyphLine line, PdfFont font)

```
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.UpdateFontAndText()
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.GetText()
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.LineRenderer.TrimFirst()
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.LineRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.ParagraphRenderer.DirectLayout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.ParagraphRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
   à iText.Layout.Renderer.CanvasRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
   à iText.Layout.RootElement`1.AddElement(IElement element)
   à iText.Layout.RootElement`1.ShowTextAligned(Paragraph p, Single x, Single y, Int32 pageNumber, Nullable`1 textAlign, Nullable`1 vertAlign, Single radAngle)
   à iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.DrawTextAppearance(Rectangle rect, PdfFont font, Single fontSize, String value, PdfFormXObject appearance)
   à iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.RegenerateTextAndChoiceField(String value, PdfName type)
   à iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.RegenerateField()
   à iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.SetValue(String value, Boolean generateAppearance)
   à CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
```

You can notice the method iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.SetValue was expecting a boolean that was missing in your call.

NB: even with the exception error and the missing boolean, the pdf has been filled.

Comment: I'll check the dependencies!